# converting list to array in array

Tags: python

I am new to programming. Here is my problem:
I am trying to convert a json file to array. But the result is there are list in array. I want to convert them into array but I don't know how to do that.
I tried using np.asarray function but didn't works
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn import neural_network
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_json('full-simplified-aircraft carrier.ndjson', lines = True, orient = 'records')
dataX = data.drawing.values
dataX = np.asarray(dataX)
print(dataX)
```

and the result:

```
[ list([[[31, 32], [0, 7]], [[27, 37, 38, 35, 21], [4, 4, 6, 7, 3]], [[25, 28, 38, 39], [5, 10, 10, 7]], [[33, 34, 32], [4, 33, 44]], [[5, 188, 254, 251, 241, 185, 45, 9, 0], [50, 50, 54, 83, 86, 90, 86, 77, 52]], [[35, 35, 43, 125, 126], [85, 91, 92, 96, 90]], [[35, 76, 80, 77], [35, 37, 41, 47]], [[53, 50, 54, 80, 78], [34, 23, 22, 23, 34]]])...
```

thanks for spending your time

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your current output and expected output. Is the result given in question expected or your current result?

Comment: Post the json file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to convent the JSON file to JSON object using

```
import json

with open("json_file.json", 'r') as json_file:
    json_obj = json.loads(json_file)
```

Now `json_obj` is either list or dict depending on your input